# Autohotkey showing clipboard content

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard

I don't know what happens but I cant get the AHK to use show clipboard content.

```
#5::MsgBox, Clipboard / Error: Function calls require a space or "(".  Use comma only 
between parameters.
#5::MsgBox % Clipboard / Error: Missing ending "%"
#5::MsgBox %Clipboard% / Warning: This variable appears to never be assigned a value.
#5::MsgBox, %Clipboard% / Error: Function calls require a space or "(".  Use comma only 
between parameters.
```

Originally I want to reuse the clipboard content to print this: e.g console.log('clipboard ', clipboard);

I always get errors, I had to reduce this problem just showing clipboard only and I always get error as well, Im total confused, why did I do wrongly ?

Thanks in advance.

Cs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in variable "Clipboard" of AHK v1 is replaced in AHK v2 by "[A_Clipboard](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/A_Clipboard.htm)". It can also be used in AHK v1.

**AHK v1:**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#5::MsgBox % Clipboard
; or
#6::MsgBox % A_Clipboard
```

AutoHotkey v2 exclusively uses expression syntax and functions. Variable names in expressions are not enclosed in percent signs.

**AHK v2:**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#5::MsgBox A_Clipboard
; or
#6::MsgBox(A_Clipboard)
```

Comment: why do we need 'A_' prefix ?

Comment: The 'A_' prefix indicates that the variable is a [built-in Variable](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Variables.htm#BuiltIn).